# Does the [functional-strength] tag need further consideration?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

The tag [functional-strength] currently has no usage guidance.  One may imagine that this could be because the phrase's definition is not well established.

One can find numerous discussions on the web debating the validity and usefulness of the qualifier "functional" in the phrase "functional strength".  Some people believe the qualifier is meaningful; others find the phrase redundant.

Regardless of lack of consensus, the tag would have a purpose for this forum if it is definably separate from other related tags such as [strength].  Conversely, if no such separation can be defined, the tag's existence does not seem warranted.

Can the [functional-strength] tag's usage guidance be written?  If not, would it be of value to consider removing or merging it?

Answer (score 3):

Functional strength training suggests different types of training than pure strength training, in my mind.

Functional Strength Tag usage guidance suggestion:

- Full body, compound movements, under load, at speeds and in ranges needed to perform life’s daily, performance or work tasks.  Questions are about training the musculo-skeletal and nervous system to co-ordinate and improve performance.

Feel free to edit.

Comment: What are some examples of strength exercises that this definition would exclude?

Comment: Isolated muscle strengthening and weight machines

Comment: Hrm. I might leave out the performance part, I wouldn't consider performance training to be functional. Functional to me means allows you to live normal daily life (Shopping, gardening, moving furniture in the house, flipping mattresses, etc), anything beyond that is sport/activity specific.

Comment: @JohnP, fine with me.  Feel free to edit.